# Struts validations problems

Tags: validation, struts

I have a form in a Tomcat server working with struts. I did not develop this environment 
so I don't know how does it work.

The form works and it returns the correct values, now I need do struts validation.
I slightly understand how it works but I'm yet to find any example that could be of any help for me.

The form have this values:

- Name
- Lastname 1
- Lastname 2
- Id number

And I need validate

- name and lastname 1 and lastname 2
- Id number and (Name or lastname 1 or lastname 2)

The valid form should be filled with one of the two options.

The form:

```html
<html:form action="registroColegiados.do" method="post">    
    <input type="hidden" id="idaccion" name="accion" value="filtrar"/>  
    <div id="filtro">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><bean:message key="paginas.listadocolegiados.encabezado.filtro" /> </legend>
            <dl>
                <!-- NOMBRE -->
                <dt>
                    <label for="texto"> <bean:message key="paginas.filtros.nombrecolegiado" /> </label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <html:text name="colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm" property="filtronombre" maxlength="50" size="50" />
                </dd>
                <!-- APELLIDO 1 -->
                <dt>
                    <label for="texto"> <bean:message key="paginas.filtros.ape1" /> </label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <html:text name="colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm" property="filtroape1" maxlength="50" size="50" />
                </dd>                   
                <!-- APELLIDO 2 -->
                <dt>
                    <label for="texto"> <bean:message key="paginas.filtros.ape2" /> </label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <html:text name="colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm" property="filtroape2" maxlength="50" size="50" />
                </dd>
                <!-- NIF -->

                <!-- N IDENTIFICACION -->
                <dt>
                    <label for="texto"> <bean:message key="paginas.filtros.ncidentificacion" /> </label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <html:text name="colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm" property="filtroncidentificacion" maxlength="50" size="50" />
                </dd>                   
                <dt>
                    <label for="areadeconocimiento">&nbsp;</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <html:submit styleId="iddefaultsubmit" property="submit" ><bean:message key="paginas.filtros.filtrar" /></html:submit>
                    <input type="hidden" id="idaccion" name="accion" value=""/>
                </dd>
          </dl>
        </fieldset>
    </div>  
</html:form>
```

There is a page named validation.xml, it has the forms validations, an example can be like this

```html
<form name ="FOGaleriaFiltrosNavegacionFormBean">
            <field
                property="filtrofechapubini"
                depends="date">
                    <arg position="0" key="filtro.fechaini"/>
                    <var>
                        <var-name>datePattern</var-name>
                        <var-value>dd/MM/yyyy</var-value>
                    </var>
            </field>
            <field
                property="filtrofechapubfin"
                depends="date">
                    <arg position="0" key="filtro.fechafin"/>
                    <var>
                        <var-name>datePattern</var-name>
                        <var-value>dd/MM/yyyy</var-value>
                    </var>
            </field>
            <field
                property="filtrofechapubfin"
                depends="mayorqueFecha">
                    <arg position="0" key="filtro.fechafin"/>
                    <arg position="1" key="filtro.fechaini"/>
                    <var>
                        <var-name>campo</var-name>
                        <var-value>filtrofechapubini</var-value>
                    </var>
            </field>
        </form>
```

The tag `depends` calls a method in the page validator-rules.xml, for example, `mayorqueFecha`calls these method

```html
<validator name="mayorqueFecha"
        classname="com.epunto.it4all.validate.ValidadorIt4all"
           method="esMayorqueFecha"
     methodParams="java.lang.Object,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.Field,
                   org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages,
                   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"
          depends=""
              msg="errors.mayorqueFecha">
         <javascript>
             <![CDATA[

                 function esMayorqueFecha(form)
                 {
                   var isValid = true;
                   var focusField = null;
                   var i = 0;
                   var fields = new Array();
                   var formName = form.getAttributeNode("name"); 

                   oMayorqueFecha = eval('new ' + formName.value + '_mayorqueFecha()');
                   for (x in oMayorqueFecha)
                   {
                       var field = form[oMayorqueFecha[x][0]];

                       if ((field.type == 'hidden' || field.type == 'text' || field.type == 'textarea') && (field.value.length > 0)  && field.disabled == false)
                       {
                           var fieldtwo = form[oMayorqueFecha[x][2]("campo")];

                           var partes  = field.value.split("/");
                           var field_value_alreves  = partes[2] + partes[1] + partes[0];
                           var partestwo  = fieldtwo.value.split("/");
                           var fieldtwo_value_alreves  = partestwo[2] + partestwo[1] + partestwo[0];

                           if(field_value_alreves < fieldtwo_value_alreves)
                           {
                                 if (i == 0)
                                 {
                                       focusField = field;
                                 }

                                 fields[i++] = oMayorqueFecha[x][1];
                                 isValid = false;
                           }
                       }
                  }

                  if (fields.length > 0)
                  {
                       focusField.focus();
                       alert(fields.join('\n'));
                  }

                  //alert(field_value_alreves);
                  //alert(fieldtwo_value_alreves);

                  return isValid;

                 }
        ]]>
              </javascript>
</validator>
```

As I already explained, I understand how it works, but I don't know how to achieve my goal.

An alternative method can be do the validation in server side with java, but i dont know how show validation message from server.

My server side is this:

```java
public ActionForward filtrar(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                                HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception

{
     ColegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm = (ColegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm)form;
     PaginatedArrayList listadoColegiados = cargarColegiados(request, form);
     //Paginacion
     colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.setNumpagina("0");
     paginar(listadoColegiados, request, colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm);
     request.setAttribute("listadoColegiados", encriptarDatos(listadoColegiados));request.setAttribute("colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm",colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm);
     return mapping.findForward("vercolegiados");
}


private PaginatedArrayList cargarColegiados(HttpServletRequest request, ActionForm form)
{
    int idiomaActual = super.getContexto().getIdidioma();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    super.cargarMenuIzquierdo(request,new Integer(-1));

    ColegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm = (ColegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm)form;

    DatosPersonalesService datospersonalesService = new DatosPersonalesService();

    SimpleDateFormat fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    PaginatedArrayList listadoColegiados = null;


    String nombre =colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltronombre();
    String ape1 = colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltroape1();
    String ape2 = colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltroape2();
    String ncolegiado = colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltroncolegiado();
    boolean validado = false;

    if(ncolegiado.equals("") || ncolegiado == null){
        if(! nombre.equals("") ||nombre == null){
            if(! ape1.equals("")||ape1 == null){
                if(! ape2.equals("")||ape2 == null){
                    validado= true;
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(! nombre.equals("") ||nombre == null){
            validado= true;
        }
        if(! ape1.equals("")||ape1 == null){
            validado= true;
        }
        if(! ape2.equals("")||ape2 == null){
            validado= true;
        }
    }


   if(validado){
        listadoColegiados = datospersonalesService.obtenerColegiados(
            (colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltronombre().equals("")) ? (null) :
            (colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltronombre()),
            (colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltroape1().equals("")) ? (null) :
            (colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltroape1()),
            (colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltroape2().equals("")) ? (null) :
            (colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltroape2()),
            (colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltroncolegiado().equals("")) ? (null) :
            (colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltroncolegiado()),
            (colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltroNif().equals("")) ? (null) :// NIF NO SE USA
            (colegiadoFiltrosNavegacionActionForm.getFiltroNif()) // NIF NO SE USA
        );
   }
    return listadoColegiados;
}
```

Comment: perhaps the simplest thing to do is to implement the validation inside the action class i.e on the server side...

Comment: I make a validation in java(server side), but how i can show the message of validation in html?

Comment: @Plirkee I edit my question

Comment: Looking at your server side code .. first thing to note is you are using `Struts` not `Struts2`  (you should edit the tag of the question)

Comment: @Plirkee edited

Comment: take a look at this .. may be it will help [action-errors-in-struts-with-example-code-how-to-display-errors-in-jsp-page](http://javaonlineguide.net/2014/09/action-errors-in-struts-with-example-code-how-to-display-errors-in-jsp-page.html)